# What is the rigorous meaning of the integral $\int_\gamma dz$ with $\gamma \in H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-curves

My question is motivated by a statement in Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

> We observe that $H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1, \mathbb{Z})$ is naturally isomorphic to the lattice $\Lambda_1$ via the map $\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma dz$.

My understanding of integration on manifolds is rather weak, but I don't think that this $dz$ is a differential form as I've seen in my differential geometry course. Silverman also treats $E(\mathbb{C})$ (for $E$ an elliptic curve with a fixed Weierstrass equation) as a complex Lie group and works with the invariant differential $dx/y$ analytically; this also makes no sense to me, and he seems to manipulate these like they're standard differential forms when proving theorems. So, for $\gamma \in H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ and $\gamma' \in H_1(E(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Z})$, can someone please help with how I should be thinking about the two integrals

$$\int_\gamma dz$$
and

$$\int_{\gamma'} \frac{dx}{y}?$$

Comment: Yes, $dz$ is precisely that sort of $1$-form. The point is that $dz$ up on $\Bbb C$ is invariant under translation by elements of the lattice $\Lambda_1$, and so descends to give a well-defined $1$-form on the torus. Similarly, $dx/y$ comes from thinking of the elliptic curve as a cubic curve in $\Bbb C^2\subset\Bbb P^2$ and using the coordinates $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$. That this is a holomorphic $1$-form on the elliptic curve takes a bit of checking.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment; this fact isn't something that I've seen before. Do you have a reference I can check that will explain what's going on with $dz$ descending to the torus?

Comment: You can certainly find stuff like this in Forster's book on Riemann surfaces. Given a submersion $\pi\colon X\to Y$ (or a $G$-action on $X$) there's a general result you can find discussed in questions on MSE indicating when a $k$-form on $X$ descends to $Y$ (or $X/G$). But it's easy to check here: If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are any two local inverses of $\pi\colon \Bbb C\to\Bbb C/\Lambda_1$, then $\psi(y) = \phi(y) + \lambda$ for some $\lambda\in\Lambda_1$. So $\psi^*(dz) = d\phi^*(z) = d(\psi^*(z) +\lambda) = d\psi^*(z) = \psi^*(dz)$, so the pullback by local inverses gives a well-defined form.

Comment: Thank you; I'll think about this!